# How to make Spring remember user after he logins until he presses 'logout' button?

Tags: java, spring

I'm developing small app using Spring. I have created register form and it writes all data in MongoDB.
[image]

Also I have login form. You type in login and pass, it finds user with this username in DB, if password the same, you login. In my case it just redirects you to home page if password is right. But how to make website remember you or something? And only when you press 'logout' it should demand you to login again?

[Login process](https://github.com/danmoop/ColorFrontier/blob/master/src/main/java/com/colorfrontier/MainApp/Controller/LoginController.java#L39)

[Register process](https://github.com/danmoop/ColorFrontier/blob/master/src/main/java/com/colorfrontier/MainApp/Controller/RegisterController.java#L28)

Thank you!

Comment: Check out the Spring Session Management - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/session-mgmt.html

Comment: Basically you need a SessionAuthenticationStrategy for your application login logic & then SessionManagementFilter to check authentication before every other request is called.

Comment: @gohil90 Is there any example with login process? All I have found are some guides with .xml files that I don't even use. I don't know how to connect SessinManager with my purpose

Comment: Check out this example with annotations -
https://www.journaldev.com/8718/spring-4-security-mvc-login-logout-example